# Flex Web Application Timeout after a specific time and redirect to login

Tags: apache-flex, timeout, blazeds

All,

We have a Flex, Blazeds & Spring based Web application. The requirement is that if the browser is idle for 30 minutes, we have to popup an error message to the user and then redirect to the login page. I have searched on this and was not able to find a suitable solution to this. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. I really appreciate that

Thanks

Harish

Comment: The answer from Wade is right. But I think I have to rephrase my question. I need to catch the Blazeds Session timeout exception in Flex and then redirect to the login page after showing a Timeout error message. My initial question was wrong. I'm sorry about that and not sure if I need to ask a new question. Please help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.  When the app loads, start a 30 minute timer and add a listener to SystemManager for mouse movements.  Each time the mouse moves reset the timer back to 30 minutes.  If the timer goes off, then display your modal dialog informing the user they've timed out.  When they click OK, send them back to the login screen.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you Wade for your reply. I forgot to add some extra information to my original post. Ours is a modular project, and it has one Main.mxml & others are module mxml files. So can I add this listener to the Main.mxml & will it work, even if the user is on any page.

Comment: Hmm, good question.  I don't have an answer for you on that one, sorry.

Comment: It does work on any page. Thanks much But the issue is, say if I have a 1 minute timer for testing, and I show an alert message saying your session timed out, there are multiple alerts showing (1 for every minute). Is there a way to restrict to only 1 alert message. Sorry for yet another noob question :)

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle this.  First, you can set the repeat count for the timer, either when you create it: new Timer(60000, 1), or after you've created it: myTimer.repeatCount = 1.  By default the value is 0, which means it just keeps repeating.  The other way to deal with this is to call myTimer.stop() after you get your timer event.  Good luck.